# Trouble reading xlsx file with pandas - how do I manually specify an engine?

Tags: pandas, xlsx

i tried reading an excel file on my desktop using the following code
`data = pd.read_excel('../Desktop/dirtydata.xlsx', header=None)`

i encountered this error

```
Value Error: Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually.
```

How do i sort this please
i have tried specifying openpyxl as engine but it would not work

Comment: What do mean openpyxl did not work? Which error was it raising?

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation of the [`pd.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) function:

> enginestr, default None
>
> If io is not a buffer or path, this must be set to identify io. > Supported engines: “xlrd”, “openpyxl”, “odf”, “pyxlsb”. Engine
> compatibility :
> “xlrd” supports old-style Excel files (.xls).
> “openpyxl” supports newer Excel file formats.
> “odf” supports OpenDocument file formats (.odf, .ods, .odt).
> “pyxlsb” supports Binary Excel files.